# Java stop word library

Tags: java

Is there any stop words library in java ?

Example:Write a java program to read input from a file, and then sort the characters within each word. Once you have done that, sort all the resulting words in ascending order and finally followed by the sum of numeric values in the file.

- Remove the special characters and stop words while processing the data
- Measure the time taken to execute the code

Please provide any stop word library for solving the above puzzle

Comment: Is it homework? If yes, please re-tag as homework. Btw for stop word -> System.exit(0)

Answer (score 6):

Apache Lucene has various stopword sets for a variety of natural languages as well as large number of other features for natural language processing. Stopwords for English available here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a library : this can be done in a few lines of code using only the standard packages.

- FileInputStream to read the file
- [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to easily get your words.
- Double.parseDouble to read the numeric values
- Arrays.sort (or any other Collection utilities) to sort your data.
- System.currentTimeMillis to measure the duration of your operation.

If you want to filter stop words, simply put them in a HashSet and filter them while reading.

Comment: The question is regarding stop words, I doubt the OP asked for the procedure to solve his problem.

Comment: Your edit takes care of what I was actually pointing out at. :-)

Comment: The problem is that the question doesn't mention in what it is related to the "stop word library" requirement. Maybe it's filtering (as I suppose in answer), maybe not...

Comment: It is filtering. The question has a lot of irrelevant stuff I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a stop word library? Simply store the stop words in a `File` and read from it, and if any such word is found in your text,delete it.

An alternative would be to maintain a `List` of stop words. Checking against a `List` would be comparatively easier.

And you probably want to look at [this](http://www.koders.com/java/fid04763A14AB2F6DCEE22818DDCE301ABBF804C571.aspx) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

See the External Links on [Wiki Page For Stop Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words)
Also Google has [some implementation](http://code.google.com/p/iestwitter/source/browse/trunk/src/edu/shu/nlt/twitter/analysis/ontology/tech/StopWords.java?spec=svn11&r=11)